# How to extract data distribution type (e.g. Poisson, binomial) from fitted GLM model object in Julia?

Tags: julia, distribution, glm

How do I extract the data distribution specified in a general linear model in `Julia`? For example, below I fit a toy example Poisson GLM. I want to extract a character string saying 'Poisson' from the model. Similarly, if the model were specified with a data distribution = `Binomial()` instead, I would like the character string to return 'Binomial'.

```
### Load packages required 
using DataFrames
using GLM

### Simulate some data for a dummy GLM 
data = DataFrame(X=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], Y=[2,4,7,3,1,6,3,2,5,1])

### Fit Poisson GLM
m1 = fit(GeneralizedLinearModel,
         @formula(Y ~ X),
         data,
         Poisson(),
         LogLink())
```

Ultimately, I want to write a function that takes an `if` statement, where `if == Poisson` then do X, `else` do Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed on the Julia Discourse a while ago [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/get-type-of-field-in-parametric-type/8210/2?u=nilshg), you can do it with:

```
julia> typeof(m1).parameters[1].parameters[1].parameters[2]
Poisson{Float64}
```